# Use selenium with Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.10

I have a project that I want to run with Docker. For this I need the image ubuntu. One component needs selenium (not as a pure test tool). How can I install/run selenium? If I install only chromium-chromedriver and xvfb, I always get the error

```
raise WebDriverException(selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

My dockerfile looks like this:

```html
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y python3 \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
    && apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev \
    && apt-get install -y portaudio19-dev \
    && apt-get install -y sox \
    && apt-get install -y flac \
    && apt-get install -y chromium-chromedriver \
    && apt-get install -y sqlite3 \
    && apt-get install -y vlc \
    && apt-get install -y xvfb

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY . /home/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python3", "main.py" ]
```

in the requirements.txt are among other things

```
selenium~=4.3.0
```

Thanks for your help!